# A property of Bernstein polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

One property of Bernstein polynomial is that
$$\sum_{k=0}^nB_k^n(x) = 1$$, where Bernstein polynomial is 
$$B_k^n(x) = {n \choose k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$

Many proof directly says that by Binomial Theorem, we can get the sum equals to 1. I can't see which property of Binomial Theorem we are using.

Answer (score 4):

$$1 =(x + ( 1 - x ) )^n = \sum_{k=0}^nB_k^n(x)$$

Comment: Damn, it's just so easy. Thank you!

Comment: Easy after the fact.  It's a trick, but I've seen it used in other contexts many times.  Someone once told me a trick that works twice is a technique.